# Calculate clustering for 3d cells in a pixel tif image

Tags: python, r, 3d, cluster-analysis

So I have a pixelized tiff image which has a bunch of cells, im trying to calculate the clustering in these tiff fimages. I looked up how to perform nearest neighbor and k-function but the issue here is that it will tell me if its clustered or not vs a random distribution (usually poisson) while in my use case first I would like to see the clustering in the tiff image itself, the cells in this tiff image but then between different tiff images that I have

Im working with a combination of Python and R scripts (on R mainly using spatstat). I tried running shannon's entropy because this gives me a number as a result which I can average on my images. I was thinking of trying Moran's I but I feel like my use case doesn't apply. The pros of Moran's I is that it gives a number between 0 and 1 if its clustered or not so it can be easily averaged

```
library(spatstat)

data <- readr::read_csv("channel1.csv")
data2 <- readr::read_csv("channel2.csv")
cells <- pp3(data$X, data$Y, data$Z, c(0, 512), c(0, 512), c(0, 80))
cells2 <- pp3(data2$X, data2$Y, data2$Z, c(0, 512), c(0, 512), c(0, 80))

nnres <- nndist.pp3(cells)
nnres2 <- nndist.pp3(cells2)
crosres <- nncross(cells, cells2)


library(misc3d)

data <- read.csv(csv_file)      
xyz <- data[,c("X", "Y", "Z")]
  
kde <- kde3d(xyz$X, xyz$Y, xyz$Z)
prob <- kde$z / sum(kde$z)
if (any(prob == 0)) {
  entropy <- 0
} else {
  entropy <- -sum(prob * log2(prob))
}
```